# How to verify multiple mock expectations with Delphi Mocks?

Tags: delphi, verify, delphi-mocks

What is the difference between mock.verify and mock.verifyAll in Delphi Mocks? Does it verify expectations of other mocks as well?
I want to verify all expectations of all my mocks created for the current unit test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell a mock of an interface that it also can mock other interfaces. This is useful if the interface you mock is asked via Supports for another interface.

`Verify` checks if the expectations of the directly mocked type while `VerifyAll` also checks the expectations of the other interfaces.

Example

```
var
  foo: TMock<IFoo>;
begin
  foo := TMock<IFoo>.Create;
  foo.Implements<IBar>;
  foo.Setup.Expect.Once.When.DoThis;
  foo.Setup<IBar>.Expect.Once.When.DoThat;

  // pass mock to tested component which 
  // calls DoThis and Supports(IBar) and calls DoThat

  foo.Verify; // checks if DoThis was called once
  foo.VerifyAll; // also checks if DoThat on the mock as IBar was called.
end;
```

Comment: So if I have many mocks I have to verify them one by one? There is no way to do that by one shot?

Comment: Personally I think that Verify/VerifyAll is an anti pattern and others do so as well - http://russellallen.info/post/2011/04/15/Moq-asserts-Verify()-vs-VerifyAll().aspx  I also think that the Moq author (which Delphi Mocks was inspired by) changed this to rather using dynamic mocks and then do the verification after with specifying what calls were expected (see https://github.com/moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#verification) - not sure if Delphi Mocks can do something similar.